# Set Selected Item of WPF Combobox to User Setting

Tags: wpf, combobox, selecteditem, selectedvalue

I have a combo box with an item source set as a collection of 'Category'.  The SelectedValuePath is the CategoryID property.  I have a user setting 'DefaultCategory' that is an integer of which should set the CategoryID.  I want the combo box to have a selection of the DefaultCategory user setting.

```
xmlns:my="clr-namespace:MyApp"

<ComboBox x:Name="cmbCategory" DisplayMemberPath="Category" SelectedValuePath="CategoryID" SelectedValue="{Binding Source={x:Static my:MySettings.Default}, Path=DefaultCategory, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create an additional application setting called **DefaultCategory_Selected** of type **int** and scope of **User**, and then binding the **SelectedIndex** property to the setting.

```
<ComboBox SelectedIndex="{Binding Path=DefaultCategory_Selected, Mode=TwoWay}" ... />
```