# selectedItem is not working in xaml

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps

i am trying to set selected item through following code but its not working:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="Sort by" Margin="10" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                <ComboBox Width="{StaticResource ComboWidth}" x:Name="sortcombo" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SortOrder}" SelectionChanged="SearchCombo_SelectionChanged" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=DefaultSortIndex}">
                    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Sort}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ComboBox>
            </StackPanel>
```

however it works fine if i use selectedIndex instead with binding to 0th index. Any thing wrong with declaration?

Comment: try to make the mode of the binding of your selecteditem TwoWay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found out the issue, actually the data source was creating new list everytime I call getData().

Answer (score 0):

By the name of your property `DefaultSortIndex` maybe you are trying to bind an `int` for `SelectedItem`.

`SeletedItem` refers to an element of your collection binded to `ItemsSource`, so the property binded to `SelectedItem` must be of type of your collection elements.

Comment: no its just a quick change i made for testing purpose, i used index which worked correctly, but when  tried changing xaml for selected item (i changed the type of property also), it didn't work.

Comment: when you say "it is not working", what do you mean? 1/ you select an item in your combobox and the value is not set in your DefaultSortIndex property? 2/ anything is selected in your combobox?

Comment: If 2/ you need to set the property DefaultSortIndex. Kind of `DefaultSortIndex = SortOrder.FirstOrDefault();`

Answer (score 0):

If you bind int value to selected item then it will not work, you should bind element for that. For int value you can set it as mentioned in following post :

[Set Selected Item of WPF Combobox to User Setting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4946167/set-selected-item-of-wpf-combobox-to-user-setting)

Comment: yes, i binded the item of type what I am using to bind itemssource, i mentioned about index, bcz it was working fine, but when i changed in xaml, i made required changes in Properties also